# How to format $with data in laravel

Tags: laravel, eloquent, model, relationship, backend

I have 3 tables, a Shirts table, a Size table, and a table that connects them called Shirt_Sizes. Shirts can have many different Sizes and Sizes can have many different shirts.

I am trying to make it so that whenever a Shirt request is called the response also returns the size. I am currently doing so by having a protected $with on shirt sizes in my shirt model:

```
protected $with = ['sizes:size'];
```

As of right now my response looks like this:

```
{
    "id": 1,
    "item_name": "A good Shirt",
    "item_description": "Description"
    "item_cost": "150.00",
    "item_sizes": [
        {
            "size": "SM"
        },
        {
            "size": "LG"
        }
    ]
}
```

I would like it to look like this:

```
{
    "id": 1,
    "item_name": "A good Shirt",
    "item_description": "Description"
    "item_cost": "150.00",
    "item_sizes": ["SM", "LG"]
}
```

How can I do this?

---Edit---

For more context here is what my Shirts Model currently looks like

```
class Shirt extends Model
{
    protected $fillable = ['item_name', 'item_description', 'item_cost'];

    protected $with = ['sizes'];

    public function sizes() {
        return $this->belongsToMany(Size::class, 'shirt_sizes', 'shirt_id', 'size_id')->select('size');
    }
}
```

I tried using pluck in my sizes function but that did not seem to work

```
public function sizes() {
            return $this->belongsToMany(Size::class, 'shirt_sizes', 'shirt_id', 'size_id')->select('size')->pluck('size');
        }
```

Answer (score 1):

The Collection method [`pluck`](https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/collections#method-pluck) does exactly what you described. It retrieves all values for a specific key in an array.

You can use it on your `item_sizes` property like this:

```
Shirt::with('sizes')->first()->item_sizes->pluck('size');
```

---

For your use case I suggest to use [Eloquent resources](https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/eloquent-resources#introduction). Their purpose is to transform any set of data for an API response.

```
use Illuminate\Http\Resources\Json\JsonResource;

class Shirt extends JsonResource
{
    public function toArray($request)
    {
        return [
            'id' => $this->id,
            'item_name' => $this->item_name,
            'item_description' => $this->item_description,
            'item_cost' => $this->item_cost,
            'item_sizes' => $this->sizes->pluck('size'),
        ];
    }
}
```

Use it in your controller like this:

```
$shirts = Shirt::with('sizes')->get();

return ShirtResource::collection($shirts);
```

This will return your collection exactly how you described but without modifying the model itself.

Comment: Hi @Dan thanks so much for replying! Please look at the edit of my post to see some more context. I also tried your pluck idea but did not work. Maybe I am putting it in the wrong place? Thank you!

Comment: Ah, now I understand what you are trying to achieve. Is your response used for an API? If that's the case I don't recommend modifying the model itself but using [Eloquent resources](https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/eloquent-resources#introduction).

Comment: I have added a small example how you could use an Eloquent resource for your case. It's far from perfect might actually fail.

Comment: Thanks for the reply! I am working on implementing this now. Will provide an update.